# need python support on freertos on 32bit arm cortexM3 board

Tags: python, interpreter, freertos

I am using free rtos on a marvell board, I want to use python at upper layer programming interface. So I need and interpreter or compiler that generates code written in python to native C.
I have tried using pymite option but in pymite there are so many functionality of python not supported, like : isinstance, bool, bytes, property, *repr* and more..

Is there anyother interpreter that can be used with free RTOS and a 32- bit ARM ?

thank you,
regards, 
shreyas.

Comment: Have you tried the full thing yet?

Comment: @lgnacio: Yes I have tried the pymite, it works at some extent like basic examples given in pymite works fine, but in case of porting our exist python project it need some python functions support which are supported in python but not supported in pymite.

Comment: No, [The Full Thing](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/ba31940588b6).

Comment: @lgnacio : No, I have not tried The Full Thing, Is it possible to use The Full Thing with free RTOS on Marvell 88MC200 board?